# CSS3 Javascript Library

Tags: css, javascript

Does a Javascript library exist that enables the usage of CSS3 properties such as rounded corners in unsupporting browsers?

Thanks,

DLiKS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are loads, but the best I've found is [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/). Make sure you read the documentation to get it working properly, but it's definitely worth checking out!

Comment: Will CSS3 PIE enable the features in non-IE unsupporting browsers?

Comment: No, but there aren't any in common usage.

Comment: I guess you're right there, IE pretty much is the only one :)